# How long does lotus root stay fresh?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, asian-cuisine

I've got some lotus root that I had in the fridge about a week before I opened it.  I left the lotus root in the water in which it was packaged and I'm wondering how long it stays fresh.  It still looks like the day I got it and it's been 2 plus weeks.  I thought what the hell, looks fine, and ate it and it's still the same old lotus root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.melissas.com/Products/Products/Lotus-Root.aspx

The link states it can be kept uncut for 2-3 weeks in the fridge, while cut pieces can last up to 5 days. I think since it's a root it should hold up much like a carrot or turnip or other like fleshed vegetable.